# SQL - Select Columns from table where another table column value equals column name list

Tags: sql

seen a lot of similar posts about parsing data based on values but nothing quite what I want to get the result column from one table that contains the column names for another table. For example:

```
 Select [col1], [col2]
 from Table1
 where (select changes as (col#)
        from table2)
```

The col# is a list of the column names I want from Table1. Table2 changes column is a comma separated list. I wanted to figure a way to be able to get each column from Table1 that's in the list from table2. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any solution would be database-specific. What RDMS are you using?

Comment: You need to provide the database vendor you are using. You need to split the values in `changes` into rows.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create the query on-the-fly. You can either do this by:

1. First fetching the data from the `changes` column into your calling application, then assembling a SQL query string from that data and execute it, or
2. Creating a dynamic statement within a stored procedure and `EXEC`ing it (or whatever your RDBMS's equivalent statement is).

Do be aware though that if the data in `changes` ever comes from user input, you are in for a world of hurt.

If you have control over the schema I would suggest to avoid this way of storing data. In general, comma-separated-lists are just unwieldy and fundamentally go against what a database is designed to do. A change-table structure with one Boolean value for each column that could change `(id, col1_changed, col2_changed)` or with a single row for each changed column `(id, changed_col_name)` would be much easier to use in a normal query.